# Шифрование QR code PHP

Tags: php, md5, криптография, hashcode, qrcode

Задача такова: использую библиотеку `PHP QR Code`.

Как сделать что бы при сканировании `QR code` запрашивался пароль который сверяется с хэшем `md5`?

Comment: Где вы это видели?

Comment: написано приложение которое считывает QR код и если он зашифрован то нужно ввести пароль который сверяется в md5 хэшем

Comment: Код в студию...

Comment: QR код в своей основе - это просто набор байтов. Как они зашифрованы (да и зашифрованы ли) определяется тем кто его составлял.

Answer (score 0):

Сам qrcode это носитель информации и ничего более.

Но можно закодировать ссылку с hash (https://testsite.com/login.php?hash=d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4). И уже на сайте может быть форма, в которой требуется ввести пароль (этот хеш соответствует паролю qwerty) и для каждого хеша свой.